# Размер массива string

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Есть массив типа `string`, в который может быть записано как 1, так и 200 значений.

```
string line[255];
```

Как получить длину массива (не установленные 255, а записанные в массив)?

Доп. вопрос: можно ли создать динамический массив `string`? Если вдруг значений будет свыше 255 - будут проблемы.

Comment: C-массив для C++ строк...вы издеваетесь?

Comment: Не занимайтесь ерундой. Используйте `std::vector<std::string>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string arr[255];

    arr[34] = "sd";
    arr[99] = "ds";

    size_t count = std::count_if(arr, arr + 255, [](std::string const& str)
    {
        return str != "";
    });

    std::cout << "count=" << count;

    return 0;
}
```

> Доп. вопрос: можно ли создать динамический массив string?

Так не лучше ли Вам воспользоваться каким-нибудь контейнером ? `std::vector`, например ?

UPD ():

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
        : m_init( false )
        , m_dummy( 0 )
    {}

void setDummy( int inDummy )
{
    m_dummy = inDummy;
    m_init = true;
}

bool initialized() const { return m_init; }

protected:
    bool    m_init;
    int     m_dummy;
};

int main() {

    Foo arr[100];

    arr[23].setDummy(2);

    size_t count = std::count_if( arr, arr + 100, []( Foo const& foo )
    {
        return foo.initialized();
    });

    std::cout << "count=" << count;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Все же в моём случае необходим `vector`.

Comment: @Виталий, всегда рад помочь :)

Answer (score 3):

Вы никак не сможете определить длину массива с реальными элементами. Либо вы должны сами поддерживать счетчик числа актуальных элементов в массиве, либо должны заносить в массив некоторое выбранное вами значение объекта типа `std::string` как граничное значение массива. И совершенно не обязательно, что таким граничным значением в контексте задачи можно использовать пустую строку.

В вашем случае вместо массива лучше использовать стандартный класс `std::vector<std::string>`, который будет для вас поддерживать число актуальных элементов в векторе, которое вы можете получить, вызвав функцию - член класса `size`.

Например,

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

//...

std::vector<std::string> line;
line.reserve( 255 );
```

Comment: Как Вы интерпретируете выражение "длина массива с реальными элементами" ? Раз Вы говорите "никак не сможете определить длину массива с реальными элементами", значит, Вы поняли суть задачи так же, как и я - найти количество элементов, которые были переинициализированны после того, как массив был создан. Иначе фраза "не сможете определить длину массива с реальными элементами" теряет смысл - мы же понимаем, что в данном случае, это 255. Тогда кто нам мешает добавить в класс метод ```initialized()```, например? И использовать возвращаемое им значение, как достаточное условие для поиска элементов?

Comment: Или же это считается плохой практикой?

Comment: @isnullxbh Все очень просто. Например, символьный массив может содержать строки, и тогда вы можете определить актуальное число элементов в массиве, используя стандартную функцию strlen.. Что касается вами упомянутого метода initialize или термина "переинициализировать", то я совершенно не понял их смысла.

Comment: Минутку, сейчас добавлю пример в пост.

Comment: Добавил пример.

Comment: @isnullxbh Первый пример кода совершенно некорректный. Массив - это непрерывный участок памяти. Поэтому если подходить к вычислению длины массива, то вычисляется размер непрерывного участка памяти. Более того, пустая строка может быть допустимым значением для элементов массива, и, второе, если вы, например, использовали с массивом алгоритм remove или remove_if, то ваш код будет подсчитывать удаленные элементы. То есть ваш код вообще ничего общего с длиной массива не имеет.

Comment: Я уверен, что тот человек, который писал этот пост, именно это и хотел увидеть. Я понимаю о чем говорите Вы, и не собираюсь оспаривать вышесказанное. Остальное - в первом комментарии к Вашему посту, и прошу извинения, если не совсем понятно излагаю свои мысли :)